# Karate UI issues with Chrome on linux

Tags: java, testing, karate

I'm seeing an odd issue running Karate UI on redhat linux using the chrome browser. The same tests work fine on windows. Has anyone experienced this or solved it? I don't know if my config is wrong or not.

10:16:12.285 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] WARN  c.i.k.driver.chrome_1643210170095 - devtools error: [id: 7, error: {code=-32602, message=Invalid parameters, data=windowId: integer value expected}]

My driver config:
{ type: 'chrome', highlight: true, headless: true, executable: '/opt/google/chrome/chrome'};

Comment: this does seem like a bug in karate code. the best thing you can do is attempt a fix and submit a PR. this is the code, and my guess is `windowId` is being sent as null but it should be not-null, the log statements above this line you showed may throw light: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.2.0.RC1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/driver/DevToolsDriver.java